# How to get rid of all whitespace in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, query, windows

```
SELECT
libary.MediaId,
library.Title,
library.`date-downloaded`,
library.Author,
library.`language`,
library.asseturl,
library.`recycle-bin`,
library.`key-asset`,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`category`, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) categoryname,
library.`tax-other`,
library.`sales-stage`
FROM
library


  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(`category`, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(`category`)-n.digit
ORDER BY
  `MediaId`,
  n.digit
```

I have a working query that takes a comma separated column called category and breaks it down so there is a matching row for each of the selection from that column.    That part works really well.   However when running the query I get whitespace in front of some of the "categoryname"s.   It seems rather inconsistent as some of the names don't have anything in front others have whitespace.

Comment: *However when running the query I get whitespace in front of some of the "categoryname"s.* There exists TRIM() function... The source of the issue is excess spaces after commas in CSV value presence.

Comment: You seem to be counting columns in a comma-separated string, not removing spaces.

Comment: @Akina - thank you - should add that as an answer.   I swore I had tried the TRIM function and it didn't help but I have a few queries that run in a certain order and probably messed that up or some syntax.   Anyways I added the TRIM function before the substring index and it got like 99% of the whitespace issues.   (for some reason some of the rows just show blank category)

Comment: *I had tried the TRIM function and it didn't help* You'd extract separate value which is not cleared with TRIM() and investigate its HEX() for the problematic starting symbols. This can be, for example, non-breaking space (code A0), tabular symbol (code 09) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Why have the `n` table at all?  The value for a given row is something like

```
 LENGTH(category) - LENGTH(REPLACE(...))
```

So:

```
SELECT ......,
       LENGTH(category) - LENGTH(REPLACE(...)) AS ct
    FROM library
    ORDER BY MediaId, ct
```